# Using a function within a Select statement for conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

So let's say I have these two tables with five columns, four of which match up perfectly but the last of which have different data types, one being char, the other being uniqueidentifier.  But I have this function, let's call it dbo.x that accepts the uniqueidentifier and hunts down the corresponding name to it elsewhere in the database.

So what I need to do is develop this script that will copy the data from table1 to table2 and convert the last column using the function.

After doing a bit of research I tried this (which clearly hasn't worked):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 AS dbo.x(table2.col5)
FROM table2
```

Can anybody give me a little advice on where to go from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have switched the expression and alias - the syntax should be as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, dbo.x(table2.col5) AS col5
FROM table2
```

In general, when you use an expression in the select statement and would like to give the resultant column a name, you write the expression first, and then its alias, e.g.

```
SELECT <expression> AS <column-name>
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, dbo.x(col5)
FROM table2
```